# What is (and why do I need) => when creating a task in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax, task

Sorry if this is obvious. I'm trying to make the jump from VB.NET to C# and I'm currently playing around with tasks. In VB.NET I can define a task like so:

```
    Dim t As New Task(Sub()
                          Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                      End Sub)
```

The part after task makes sense to me, I'm creating a new method.

In C# it looks like:

```
        Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });
```

I'm guessing the `()` is stating it's a new method but what is and why do I need `=>`.

Comment: @BenReich my bad, I did search first but didn't come up with this. Still though, the `=>` seems superfluous but that's probably because I've only ever worked with vb.net

Comment: The () indicate the argument list for the method.  In this case, you don't have any arguments, but you need to the parenthesis anyway

Comment: I don't think anyone has answered "why" - I think it's required to eliminate any possible ambiguity in the parsing of C# code (this was probably also the reason "delegate" was used in 'legacy' C# code).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `=>` is the syntax used by C# to define a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

It is the equivelent of the `Sub()` / `End Sub` in your VB Task constructor.

Instead of defining a delegate as:

```
Dim del as Action = Sub() Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

In C#, you would write:

```
Action del = () => Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The Task just moves this same syntax into the constructor, and declares it inline.

Answer (score 1):

That example is creating the task using a lamda expression for the function definition. You could also create it using a delegate or a pre-defined function like this:

```
void MyFunction() {
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

and creating your Task like this:

```
Task t = new Task(MyFunction);
```

Please see the following link for more information on lamda expressions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you like, you can use this equivalent syntax:

```
Task t = new Task(delegate()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
});
```

But in C# people pretty much always use the lambda syntax.